# Conditionally add a component to a shell pipeline

Tags: bash, pipeline

I want to conditionally add `sort` to a shell pipeline, but I'm getting a syntax error when I try:

```
want_sorting=0
generate_data() { for ((i=0; i<10; i++)); do echo "$RANDOM"; done; }
consume_data() {
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "got data: $line"
  done
}

generate_data |
  if [ "$want_sorting" = 1 ]; then
    sort |
  fi
  consume_data
```

However, this throws a syntax error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
```

How can I add `sort |` to the pipeline only if `want_sorting` is set?

Comment: Paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/ recommendations.

Comment: i've already tried but it did not proposed a solution .. probably I need not use IF the second time but rather antyher trick to activae sort command in the case of some condition

Comment: And `sort -k1,1 | fi` not being valid is... kind of obvious, no? You can't have a trailing pipe like that.

Comment: Also, `==` isn't guaranteed to work in `[` in the first place. The only POSIX-standardized string equality operator in `test` is `=`

Comment: i've jsut updated my question precising my question. with a single = it does not work as well..

Comment: With a single `=` it'll at least not break on ash or dash. It doesn't fix your _current_ problem, but it fixes other problems you'd have later if you left it unresolved.

Comment: btw, all-caps variable names are used for variables meaningful to the shell or operating system -- names you define yourself should be lowercase. See the relevant POSIX standard at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that shell and environment variables share a namespace (setting the former will overwrite the latter should one exist with the same name).

Comment: I edited your code into a proper [mre]. Please try to do this yourself in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that items are split into pipeline components, each of which has a different copy of the shell running it in parallel; so a single `if` statement can't have its `fi` split off into a different pipeline component.

You can't make a conditional pipeline entry easily, but you *can* easily make a pipeline entry decide whether to run a command that does something (like `sort`) or one that doesn't do anything at all (like `cat`).

```
generate_data |
  if [ "$want_sorting" = 1 ]; then
    sort -k1,1
  else
    cat
  fi |
  consume_data
```

---

Now, the slightly less-easy approach:

To get rid of this copy of `cat` one can use a shell function that only conditionally creates the pipeline component with `sort` before running whatever was supposed to come later in the pipe; something like:

```
maybe_sort_then() {
  if [ "$want_sorting" = 1 ]; then
    sort | "$@"
  else
    "$@"
  fi
}

generate_data |
  maybe_sort_then consume_data
```

Comment: that works! I just did not understood why cat is used after else in the second case

Comment: Because you have to have _something_ there (that reads from stdin and writes to stdout to keep the pipeline going), and `cat` is something.

Comment: Right, I gotcha thank you very much!

Comment: just a qick question. why the following activation of the awk script within the same workflow (just before sort) does not work : if [ "$ALL_DATA" = 0 ]; then awk 'NR > 1 && $5 > 0.05 {print ($1 ~ /^lig/ ? $2 : $1 ), $5}' $file |; else cat; fi

Comment: The `|;` is the problem. Leave the `|` out. Any pipe to a later component should come after the `fi`.

Comment: thank you! is it better to use in such flow elif [ "$ALL_DATA" = 1 ]; then  or just else ?  (if there is only two possibilities)

Comment: Just else, definitely.

Comment: just an additional question: the pipeline does not work correctly if I pipe another awk (with new condition in the simular format) AFTER the SORT condition in the following manner: if [ "$COLOR_DATA" = 1 ]; then
awk -v colors='0x4472c4 0xed7d31' '
    BEGIN { nc = split(colors,clrArr) }
    { print $0, clrArr[NR % nc + 1] }
'
else cat; fi

Comment: I really need to see that with formatting in a context where I can see the problem myself. As a one-liner, at minimum, it's missing a `;` before the `else`.

Comment: right, thank you! i guess it would be better to create a new topic showing entirely my pippeline. Actually this is not one-liner so no need for ; I've just added the AWK post-processing after sort condition keeping exactly the same format of the condition. It works OK when the triger is activated and does not work when the condition pass it (goes in else). I believe this could be due to the | after the fi (of SORT condition) which normally is not required (nothing to pipe!) if we pass the next AWK condition: fi | if [ "$COLOR_DATA" = 1 ]; then ...

Comment: well, here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74017854/bash-multiple-conditions-in-a-multiple-shell-pipeline