# bash/gnuplot: IF condition within batch script for gnuplot

Tags: bash, if-statement, awk, gnuplot

My bash script incorporates multiple pipeline which process input data using AWK SORT and again AWK and send it to gnuplot for ploting. Each of the pre-processing steps in the pipeline are triggered using IF conditions that allows to selectively activate them.

```
echo "vizualisation of data with Gnuplot + AWK + SORT"
{
    echo '$data << EOD'
    if [ "$ALL_DATA" = 0 ]; then
        awk -v filt="$filt" 'NR > 1 && $5 > filt {print ($1 ~ /^lig/ ? $2 : $1 ), $5}' "$file"
    else
        awk 'NR > 1 {print ($1 ~ /^lig/ ? $2 : $1 ), $5}' "$file"
    fi |
    if [ "$SORT_BARS" = 1 ]; then
        sort -k1,1
    else cat; fi |
    if [ "$COLOR_DATA" = 1 ]; then
        awk -v colors="$color1 $color2 $color3" '
            BEGIN { nc = split(colors,clrArr) }
            { print $0, clrArr[NR % nc + 1] }
        '
    else cat; fi
    echo 'EOD'
    #.... !!NB : print script for gnuplot using TWO conditions !!
    cat << EOF
    set term pngcairo size 800,600
    set xlabel "H-bond donor, residue"
    set ylabel "Fraction, %"
    # TWO OPTIONS FOR BAR VISUALISATIONS:
    # 1 - use it with non-colored bars"
    # should be activated when [ "$COLOR_DATA" = 0 ]
    plot "\$data" using 0:2:xtic(1) with boxes, "" using 0:2:2 with labels offset 0,1
    # 2 - or use it with colored bars:
    # # should be activated when [ "$COLOR_DATA" = 1 ]
    plot \$data using 0:2:3:xtic(1) with boxes lc rgb var, \
            '' using 0:2:2 with labels offset 0,1

EOF
} | gnuplot > output.png
```

How could I integrate a triger guided by [ "$COLOR_DATA" = 0/1 ] condition inside the cat << EOF part that should create two different versions of the batch script for gnuplot depending on the provided option for "$COLOR_DATA" ?

Comment: Beyond that -- can you make this a [mre] people can test on their own? We shouldn't need to imagine a `...print script for gnuplot...` before we can reproduce your problem. Similarly, we shouldn't need to guess what "does not send data to gnuplot correctly" means.

Comment: When you say "MAKE PROBLEMS" -- what problems? Be specific, and include those specifics _in the question itself_. Similarly, to the extent that you can take gnuplot out of your question, _do that_; simplifying your problem lets people who don't have your dataset (or don't have gnuplot installed at all) reproduce the problem and test their proposed answers.

Comment: BTW, I think you still have some serious misunderstandings of what pipes are and how they work. They separate pieces. Each `if` has to be _one piece_. There's a reason every time you try something like `if foo; then bar |; fi` or `if foo; then | bar; fi` it fails: it's attempting to split the `if` into two different commands, one on each side of the `|`

Comment: Instead of piping it to `gnuplot` redirect it to a file so you can see what's being piped.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's what they're doing: `if foo; then bar; else baz; fi | if foo; then bar; else baz; fi | ...`

Comment: @Barmar, I know, because I helped them come up with that form in a prior question.

Comment: @Barmar, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73989257/conditionally-add-a-component-to-a-shell-pipeline/73989469?noredirect=1#comment130690490_73989469 for context -- but here, when they're talking about things they tried that didn't work, they attempted "to put the pipe in the awk after if", as in, `if [ "$COLOR_DATA" = 1 ]; then | awk ...`; I'd hoped that the prior question's answer would have ended any further attempts along those lines, so I have the takeaway that that prior answer didn't explain the relevant fundamentals clearly enough.

Comment: @JamesStarlight, ...also, think about adding some `tee`s to your pipelines. Add `| tee stage1.txt |` after the first bit of awk, `| tee stage2.txt |` after the second, etc -- then you can read through those files and see where the data moving through the pipeline first differs from what you expect.

Comment: update: everything was  fine codition flow, actually this was a problem in the gnuplot script. I am going to edit my first topic!!